# Error in github? why im i getting this error has been days i cant download the project

Tags: git, github, git-clone

This fatal error shows up on github everytime I try to clone the project I tried to download it from the github website but still gets the same error, I have to find a solution because it takes 14-16hrs to download it and as soon is finished I try to open it a lot of files haven't got downloaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try connecting using ssh instead of using http to clone. Http is more prone for timeouts in case of large repositories.

Steps to generate SSH:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Add the ssh to your github account and your local identity.

Then use clone command:

```
git clone git@github.com:your_org/your_repository.git
```

If the clone still fails, you can use following approach:
Turn off compression:

```
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Start with shallow clone first with depth 1.

```
git clone --depth=1 <repo>
```

Once that is successful, you can incrementally pull more commit histories by

```
git fetch --depth=5

git fetch --depth=50
```

and so on.
Finally run following to sync all remaining history.

```
git fetch --unshallow
```